# Inserting a specified amount of rows into a table from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I insert batches or a specified amount of rows into a table from another table?

Example: Insert first 1000 rows into table b from table a.
Then I want to insert the next 1000 rows into table from table a where it left off and so on.

A typical statement would be:

```
insert into A
select top 1000 from table b
```

How can I now, select the next 1000 rows into table b from where it left off?
Select top 1000 from table b

Comment: Typically something like this would be done with a cursor. You would want to use TOP and ORDER BY in the select statement. There are literally thousands of examples of this all over the internet.

Comment: Perhaps this works `insert into A select * from B order by id offset 1000 fetch first 1000 rows only`.

Comment: @SeanLange -- typically this kind of thing would not be done with a cursor, cursors are horribly slow and you should never use them when working with database systems.

Comment: @Hogan it sounds like a very typical case of needing to insert large amounts of rows and not wanting to kill your server. I certainly did NOT mean single RBAR inserts. I mean to use a while loop to insert in large batches....no idea why I said cursor. UGH!!!

Comment: @SeanLange - I stand by my statements.  EVEN when doing big batch statements you don't want to use a cursor.

Comment: @Hogan, I know TOP always has been the SQL Server way, but isn't ANSI SQL's FETCH FIRST also supported nowadays?

Comment: @Hogan SQL Server also supports `OFFSET X ROWS FETCH NEXT Y ROWS ONLY` as of SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Siyual - sounds nice -- a google search for it did not show that microsoft documentation -- do you have a link?

Comment: @Hogan - https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2314819

Comment: I just found it --  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385%28v=sql.110%29.aspx  Very cool, thanks @Siyual

Answer (score 1):

hopefully you have a pk

```
select 1  -- to get a @@rowcount > 0
while (@@rowcount > 0)  
begin
   insert into table2 (id, val)
   select top (1000)
          table1.id, table1.val 
     from table1 
     left join table2
          on table1.id = table2.id  
    where table2.id is null 
    order by table1.id -- keep index fragmentaion down 
end
```

I use this a lot and it is very efficient
PK joins are efficient

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT
        *
        ROW_NUMBER() (ORDER BY [SomeDateOrIdField]) AS 'InsertId'
    FROM
        Table
    )
INSERT INTO NewTable
SELECT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    InsertId BETWEEN 1 AND 1000
```

Then repeat the query for the next 1000 records by adjusting the WHERE clause BETWEEN values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a loop in T-SQL that will do what you want.  Fill in the blanks with your table names and column names.

```
Declare @checkCount INT
Declare @loopCount INT


Set @checkCount = 1 -- This will make the loop run at least once
Set @loopCount = 0

While @checkCount > 0 -- AND @loopCount < 5
begin


    Insert into [Table2]
        (<Your column names here>)
        (Select Top 1000 <Your column names here> from Table1
          where <key> NOT IN (Select <key> from [Table2]))

    Select @checkCount = Count(*)
      from Table1
     where <key> NOT IN (Select <key> from [Table2])

    Set @loopCount = @loopCount + 1
End
```

Comment: See my @@rowcount answer.  It will be faster.